# How to redirect logs from a background process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have C++ program called `MyApp` like below

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    for(int a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
        std::cout << "Hello stackoverflow" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I built it for Linux to run as a console application. I run it from the terminal just by calling it with the following command.

```
MyApp & >> /some/output.txt
```

**Question:**
As you can see above, I want the log output to go into `/some/output.txt`. That works great. But the problem is that the logs parallel to adding the `cout`s into the txt file, it keeps spamming the console as well! How can I make the `cout`s go into `/some/output.txt` and not spam the console? Is there a way to do that or should I have to change the `C++` logic in `MyApp` to do that?

Comment: With the example you've shown, it does spam the terminal as you claim, as all the stdout content is written to the file. Do you have some log statements written to the standard error stream?

Comment: No. I don't have any log statements written into the error stream. I just wish to know how to deal with `cout`s and force them into a txt file without having to change the C++ code of the application itself (If feasible).

Comment: You don't need to change your code at all. Simply redirect stdout (the stream that cout writes to) and stderr as per https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: I made an important edit. I am running `MyApp` in the background. So the command I run is  `MyApp & >> /some/output.txt`

Comment: MyApp > /tmp/output.txt &

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74520/can-i-redirect-output-to-a-log-file-and-background-a-process-at-the-same-time for a longer explanation

Comment: @BrianAgnew your suggestion of `MyApp > /tmp/output.txt &` does the trick. I can accept it as an answer if you post one. Or may be I should close the question since there is you mentioned a link having the explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyApp > /tmp/output.txt & – Brian Agnew